# Wishes I was gone vs. wishes I were gone

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs

"She wishes I were gone" has [7](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=hoZ&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQcbIBRkWHhz0PpTBf7PFgk-2GVpA%3A1579524691624&ei=U6IlXoHlJZmIr7wP776xsAw&q=%22She%20wishes%20I%20were%20gone%22&oq=%22She%20wishes%20I%20were%20gone%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...82783.83871.0.84060.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.MT7Wfef_bRg) results on Google Books.

"She wishes I was gone" has [3](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=qAF&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNRYiefL93_L8vE5m2gu9WK-JwVO9A%3A1579524781263&ei=raIlXrbSD6vemAWjq6igDw&q=%22She%20wishes%20I%20was%20gone%22&oq=%22She%20wishes%20I%20was%20gone%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...37785.37927.0.38644.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.h9whfpWS5_4).

The difference in results isn't very big.

What's the correct version? Or both are correct depending on the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> She wishes I **were** gone.

This is the grammatically correct phrase. The other phrase is incorrect from a grammar perspective, although it is used/seen due to "I was" sounding more natural than "I were".